# Properly delete and then restore everything in iCloud Photos

Tags: icloud, backup, photos

Due to what seems to be a very unusual bug, the storage counter for my iCloud account is stuck thinking that I have occupied more Photos storage than I really have. I was briefly in contact with Apple support, and I want to empty iCloud of photos and videos completely (basically down to 0 bytes). I want to do this to make sure that the storage usage is properly calculated.

After deleting all Photo/Video content in iCloud, I then want to restore the photos, videos, and preferably also all meta data (*dates, folders, locations…*) in its entirety.

**Question**: What would be the suggestible way to accomplish this?

I have Photos on my iMac set to "Download and keep all originals". Can I simply make a backup of `Photos Library.photoslibrary`, then go to iCloud.com and delete everything in the "*Photos app*", and somehow restore everything from the `photoslibrary` file?

I want to be absolutely sure that everything on iCloud is properly saved and restored. Even if that means that I have to download everything from iCloud.com – in case that the `photoslibrary` file for some discrepant reason may be incomplete relative to what's actually in iCloud.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Download and keep all originals" is the correct setting to get all your photos onto your Mac. These originals are stored in `Photos Library.photoslibrary`, you can check the exact location of your library by launching the photos app while pressing *option*.
You can also check for syncing problems by creating a smart album, looking for files failed to sync.

After you have double-checked all of the above and saved your library on a secure place you go to **System Preferences -> iCloud** and choose *Manage* in the lower right corner (I don't know the exact translation, I'm using my Mac in another language). In the popup menu, choose photos and then delete from *iCloud Drive*.

The photos will be stored online for the next 30 days, so you are able to download them again, in case you made a mistake. After that period (make yourself a calendar entry) you can activate iCloud Photo Library again, and all your files will be uploaded again.